# Anaconda - update conda OSError 'Operation timed out'

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, anaconda, conda

I've just downloaded Anaconda with Python 2.7, I'm following these instructions:
https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/getting-started.html#managing-conda

I've successfully retrieved the current version of conda:

```
conda 4.3.27
```

However, after trying to follow the second step which is updating conda i am getting the following error:

```
Users-MacBook-Pro:~ UserName$ conda update conda
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment /Users/UserName/anaconda2:

The following packages will be UPDATED:

conda: 4.3.27-py27h94ab009_0 --> 4.3.30-py27h407ed3a_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(337): An error occurred while 
uninstalling package 'defaults::conda-4.3.27-py27h94ab009_0'.
OSError(60, 'Operation timed out')
Attempting to roll back.

OSError(60, 'Operation timed out')
```

Any idea why this is failing?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
conda update conda
```

I ran

```
sudo conda update conda
```

which worked.

Not sure why though, so if anyone could tell me that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying conda update --all